# Selected text index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to find text index using javascript/jquery, but i am not get the exact solution for it.

Consider the text is like this ...

```
 Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.Hi all. hello world. Hi all. Hello world.
```

How can i get the exact position of selected 'Hello' word on any line?
   I tried indexOf, but it is giving me first hello text index.
   Please any one suggest solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"? Do you mean "clicked on"?

Comment: Or do you mean highlighted?

Comment: Can you please tell us that what is the code block that you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this out http://help.dottoro.com/ljkstboe.php

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    selection = window.getSelection();
    index = selection.anchorOffset;
    console.log(index);
});
```

demo: http://slackware.koding.com/getSelDemo.html

Comment: This is pretty cool. I think I'm gonna start looking into all the fields and functions accessible from window.

Comment: This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153630/selected-text-editing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var foo="yourstring";
var pos = foo.indexOf("Hello");
while(pos > -1) {
   document.write(pos + "<br />");
   pos = foo.indexOf("Hello", pos+1);
}
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvRhj/)

Comment: This solution only provides the indexes of all of the "hello" words. What the OP wants is to know the index of the selection

Comment: here is my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153630/selected-text-editing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why indexOf is not working for you. Same is working for me. Please check the below fiddle.

[HTML]

```
 <p id="demo">Click the button to locate where in the string a specifed value occurs.     </p>

 <input type="button" id="btn" value="click"/>
```

[Script]

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

 var str="Hello world, hello to the universe.";
 var n=str.indexOf("hello");
  alert(n)
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YWPYp/)

Comment: This is somethign the OP has already tried. He wants to know the postion of a selected text. indexOF works for him but gives the first ocurrence in the string.

Comment: here is my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153630/selected-text-editing