# selected text editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a iPhone app developer.I am changing the color of selected text. This is working fine for me. But when there are few repeated words for example

> Hi All.Hello world.I am iPhone app developer.Hello world.Stack overflow.Hello world.

Here 'Hello' text is repeating. When i am selecting last 'Hello' text it is giving me first 'Hello' text index.  I tried `indexOf(),search()` and `anchorOffset()` but this is not working.

Following is my code.

```
function heighlightText(data) {
    var selectedText = window.getSelection();

    var textd=$("#data").html(); // this will give me whole text.

    var normalText = $("#data").text();
    var startPosition = normalText.search(selectedText);                        // this will give selected text start position.
    var getPosition = selectedText.toString();
    var endPosition = parseInt(getPosition.length) + parseInt(startPosition);   // this will give selected text end position.

    var textToReplace = "<span id='" + startPosition + "' class='highlightedText' onclick=\"myOnclikFunction('"+selectedText+"')\"> "+selectedText+"</span>";

    var startPart = textd.substr(0,startPosition);
    var lastPart = textd.substr(endPosition,textd.length);
    var reT = startPart + textToReplace + lastPart;

    $("#data").html(reT);
}
```

Hy HTML:

```
<style type = "text/css">
    #data {
        font-size : 20px;
        color : black;
    }

    .highlightedText {
        background-color : red;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id = "data" >Lots of text here...
    <div/>
</body>
```

Can any one suggest solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just colouring the text, then Stefan's answer is the most reliable and easiest way:

```
document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "#0000FF");
```

However, it looks as though you're adding a class and a click handler, so you need more flexibility.

First, there is no way to get a selection as offsets within an HTML representation of the DOM reliably. You can get the selection as offsets within nodes directly via `anchorOffset`, `anchorNode`, `focusOffset` and `focusNode`, or as a [DOM range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range). If the selection is completely contained within a single text node, you can use the range's `surroundContents()` method:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UvBTq/

Code:

```
function highlightText(data) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var selectedText = range.toString();

        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.id = "span_" + range.startOffset + "_" + range.endOffset;
        span.className = "highlightedText";
        span.onclick = function() {
            myOnclikFunction(selectedText);
        };

        range.surroundContents(span);

        // Restore selection
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

However, this is very brittle and will only work when the selection is completely contained within a single text node. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may need a more flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected text, you have to use the getSelection javascript method. i don't know if that method is available on iphone browser, but here is a general function that combines the methods for all browsers.

```
function getSelected() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection
    && window.getSelection().toString()
    && $(window.getSelection()).attr('type') != "Caret") {
        text = window.getSelection();
        return text;
    }
    else if (document.getSelection
    && document.getSelection().toString()
    && $(document.getSelection()).attr('type') != "Caret") {
        text = document.getSelection();
        return text;
    }
    else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();

        if (!(typeof selection === "undefined")
        && selection.text
        && selection.text.toString()) {
            text = selection.text;
            return text;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643635/how-to-get-selected-html-text-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use `contenteditable="true"` `and document.execCommand('ForeColor', false, 'YOURCOLOR');` instead

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>- jsFiddle demo</title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            $('#color').click(function () {
                document.execCommand('ForeColor', false, '0000FF');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p contenteditable="true">Hello world</p>
    <button id="color">Change Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/WQKCw/1/

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a good answer, although the code in the question does seem to imply that the `<span>` used to surround the selected text is doing more than just colouring the text.

Comment: nice somebody is wondering too. Well their is another document.executeComand for creating spans but I can't find it at the moment...

Comment: There's `InsertHTML` but that pastes over the existing selection rather than surrounding it.